# Need Tomcat5 configured to listen on all interfaces

Tags: tomcat

I have [tomcat5](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-55.cgi) installed on CentOS. which is configured to listen only from 127.0.0.1. How do I configure Tomcat to listen from all interfaces.

Connector port config is as under:

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
       connectionTimeout="20000" 
       URIEncoding="UTF-8"
       address="0.0.0.0"
       redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `iptables -L` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the connector stanza in your `server.xml` file.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           address="0.0.0.0"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

You need to add/change the `address` attribute. Don't forget to restart your tomcat server after that.

Comment: changed as you advised. still i am unable to access tomcat

Comment: I can't see the `address` attribute in your connector.

Comment: added the address attribute. but still having the same problem..

Comment: @Asghar Did you restart the service after making the change?  Can you confirm which address it's listening on with `netstat`?

Comment: `address="0.0.0.0"` mean listen on all interfaces