# google cloud firewall rule not working

Tags: networking, firewall, http, google-cloud-platform

I have a google cloud server with tomcat installation on port 8080.

I can open the tomcat and deployed application in the browser from the google cloud instance but even after adding the firewall rule to open the traffic on 8080 port is not working from my laptop (i.e. internet)

I have spent hours finding the solution but somehow its just not working. If this doesn't work then I might have to move all my servers to AWS. as all  servers are having this issue. I tried to recreate a network but couldn't find a way to switch from default network to new network.

**Firewall rules**

```
default-allow-http
    0.0.0.0/0   tcp:80, tcp:8080, udp:8080
    Apply to all targets

default-allow-https
    0.0.0.0/0   tcp:443     https-server

default-allow-icmp
    0.0.0.0/0   icmp    Apply to all targets

default-allow-internal
    10.128.0.0/9,
    tcp:0-65535, udp:0-65535,
    Apply to all targets

default-allow-rdp
    0.0.0.0/0   tcp:3389, tcp:8080  Apply to all targets

default-allow-ssh
    0.0.0.0/0   tcp:22  Apply to all targets
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved? If not, can you run 'netstat -plnt' command inside your server and post the output?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change the settings of your Tomcat config to listen to `0.0.0.0` in `server.xml` (as per this [other answer suggests](https://serverfault.com/questions/376292/need-tomcat5-configured-to-listen-on-all-interfaces)).

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           address="0.0.0.0"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```